# Prevent a cascade with CSS

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the HTML below. Is there any way to prevent the background-color cascading into the inner table? **I.E.** leaving the HTML exactly as it is and only modifying the CSS class can I achieve this:

[image]

```css
.myClass table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myClass">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>World</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried looking at nth-child()?

Comment: in this case: .myClas table td:nth-child(2){background-color: red;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a code snippet for you:

```css
.myClass table td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myClass">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>World</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Basically you tell CSS to make the background of the 2nd TD in the table the red background:

```
.myClass table td:nth-child(2){
    background-color:red;
}
```

More info on nth-child() [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: note that if you add a second TD to the nested table it will also be red. See @Wim Mertens' answer on how to only select the table in the `.myClass` div ( .myClass > table { background-color: red } ), note the `>`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

`.myClass > table { background: red; }`

Comment: For the record: this DOES only select the first table, not the nested one, so it's very useful in these situations. This will only apply the CSS to the first table directly under the .myClass div, and not cascade. But you'll have to set 'table{ background-color: white }' as well...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to prevent the background-color cascading into the
>   inner table?

Yes. You can style the table:

```
.myClass table {background: red;}
```

and then style the table nested inside the table:

```
.myClass table table {background: white;}
```

```css
.myClass table {
    background-color: red;
}

.myClass table table {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "myClass">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Hello</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>World</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```