# Prevent an HTML sub-table from getting cascade style

Tags: html, css

If I have the HTML below I want to find a single CSS class definition that will effect the outermost table but not the sub tables. Without changing the HTML can I get `.myClass` to do this:

[image]

I was playing around with the not selector but couldn't get it to work.

```css
.myClass tr td div :not(table) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myClass">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>My</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>World</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent a cascade with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340120/prevent-a-cascade-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do this with pure css without changing your html.

You can do it with jQuery or by simply putting the 'My' inside of a span, because text is not accesible by a selector.

But in all fairness your question was partly answered by @Pangloss. To access the outer table, just use `>`. Your problem lies in the fact that on the 2nd and 3rd rows, you still have the outer table present. Your question should actually be something like "What's the selector for an element that does not have a specific child type", and then you would find that you cannot target a parent of an element on css yet.

Answer (score 0):

The first cell is the first div inside the first tr, we can target this using the following:

```css
tr:first-child div:first-child{
  background:red;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
tr:first-child div:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myClass">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>My</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>World</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```